# JqGrid Custom Button Not Executing Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

So I have added a custom button to the pager of my JqGrid Table. I have attempted to test it by adding a simple alert("hello") function to the onClick parameter like so:

```
jQuery("#jsonmap").jqGrid('navGrid','#pjmap',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,refresh:true}).
                jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pjmap",{caption:"Export to Excel",buttonicon:"", onclickButton: function(){ 
      alert("Hello");
   }, position:"last",title:"",cursor:"pointer"});
```

The button shows up properly on the JqGRid when it is generated on the webpage, but when I click on it nothing happens, no alert nothing.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: Are you finding any error in firebug console when the click event is triggered  ?

Comment: well as is usually the case, I found the error immediately after asking a question about it... I have "onclickButton" when it should be "onClickButton" This question can be closed

Comment: I dont have the rights to close the question, i suppose you remove it by yourself. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use onClickButton, it should be in camel case